# Difference and example of Directives in FIELD and FIELD_DEFINITION

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Like the title, I know the difference is the position of the directives, but my question is exists other difference? or advantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `FIELD` directive is used client-side.

```
query {
  someField @someDirective
}
```

A `FIELD_DEFINITION` directive is used server-side.

```
type Query {
  someField: String @someDirective
}
```

Server-side directives affect how a schema is initially created. Client-side directives modify how an individual operation is executed.

Comment: Oh, I understand, anothe question, ¿how I create a FIELD directive with laravel-lighthouse, all example are FIELD_DEFINITION? u.u

Comment: https://lighthouse-php.com/4.16/custom-directives/getting-started.html#directive-interfaces